# How to reload div content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script that loads content into a div. When you click on a menu item, the content gets loaded inside of "contentarea" and the URL gets updated. That part works perfectly. However, I would also like to be able to click inside of the div (once content has been loaded into it), and load another page in its place. For example, the Forms page gets loaded into contentarea, and inside of the forms page there is a link to the contact us page. When I click on the link, I would like for the forms page to be cleared from content area and the contact us page to be loaded in its place. See the following image:

[image: Jquery load feature]

With the way my script is setup right now, content only loads when I click from outside of the div.

Here's the code I need to modify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Jquery loader
function getHash() {
    return window.location.hash
}

$("a").on("click", function (e) {

    page = this.href.replace("#", "") + ".html",
        hash = $(this).prop("hash");


    $('#contentarea').load(page, function () {
        if (page.match("home.html")) {
            history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
        } else {
            location.hash = hash;
        };



    });

});

//on pageload

history.pushState
var hash = getHash();
if (hash) {
    $("a[href='" + hash + "']").trigger("click");
} else {
    $("a[href='#home']").trigger("click");
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick reload the div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413200/onclick-reload-the-div-only)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, i would propose this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on( 'click', 'a', function( e ) {
        $('#contentarea').load( e.target.href );
    });
});
```

But if you are creating an app, and you are applying it globally, in your case i would reconsider your structure to avoid major changes on your code later. I've passed on that, because you have to manage **states** (variables of page/state if they exist: like errors, title, url, and obviously content) and determine which of them is active or not to pass to next page or not. Then you have to filter links that you don't want to propague to your history states handler cause you just don't want to...

On some cases, you can't apply existent frameworks on your project because the best approach is to use their code on your framework (yes, create your own framework).

I hope this could help you! :)